# Widget of products with catalog rule

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-rules, widget-instance

I've used the following function to retrieve the products to display products on a widget filtered by catalog rules. The products listed in view page shows that rules are applied.

But the function `getMatchingProductIds()` retrieves all product IDs other than applied products

```
$catalog_rule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load(2);  
$skus = $catalog_rule->getMatchingProductIds();

print_r($skus);
```

How to retrieve the products on which the rule is applied?

Comment: and what's the question here?

Comment: How to retrieve the products on which the rule is applied?

Answer (score -1):

At last I found a way to do this. I know it is a not a big thing.But as a beginner it was helpful for me and want to help someone in search of this.

$product_ids= Mage::getModel('catalogrule/resource_rule')->getRuleProductIds(2);

// 2 is rule id

It retrieves all the product ids on which the rule is applied